# Problem with rest api paths in Tomcat using springboot App

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I cant get to the rest apis path when deploying in tomcat. I can access my rest api when it's local. but when I deploy my .war to tomcat it seems there is some configuration I should do. my app doesn't have UI i'm just using swagger docs to try out my Rest APi

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/email") 
public class EmailController {

private final NotificationEmail email;

@Autowired
public EmailController(NotificationEmail email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@ApiOperation(value = "Send new Email")
@PostMapping(value = "")
public ResponseEntity<Status> sendEmail(@RequestBody NotifyRequest notifyRequest) throws UnknownException {
    this.email.sendEmail(notifyRequest);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfjm8.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
@RestController   //for spring to know the type of class it is
@RequestMapping("/email") 
public class EmailController {

private final NotificationEmail email;

@Autowired
public EmailController(NotificationEmail email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@ApiOperation(value = "Send new Email")
@PostMapping(value = "")
public ResponseEntity<Status> sendEmail(@RequestBody NotifyRequest notifyRequest) throws UnknownException {
    this.email.sendEmail(notifyRequest);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I guess you were missing, @RestController annotation, please try and let me know if above code works.

Comment: No i didn't miss it. I have it right and i can get access it on localhost but when I deploy it on tomcat I can't access it.

Comment: I fixed the question now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the war file was not running and I got confused because the embedded swagger page was running even though the app wasn’t.